# Plugin [id: 'io.spring.dependency-management', version: '1.0.5.RELEASE', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: spring, gradle

I forked ([spring-frameword](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework))
when I use idea build it,some wrong.

```
Plugin [id: 'io.spring.dependency-management', version: '1.0.5.RELEASE', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.spring.dependency-management:io.spring.dependency-management.gradle.plugin:1.0.5.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  Open File

Comment: Maybe u are behind a proxy. Consider adding
systemProp.http.proxyHost=hostname
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=de\\username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=xxx
to your gradle.properties

Comment: It's work.I forgot that I set gradle.properties before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for @Raffaele,just check you gradle.properties first.
I use Mac and the default setting,in .gragle.